# Running in TestNG

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I am using TestNG with Intellij. I have two classes, one with logic and one with 3 @Test methods. On execution its not running the last 2 methods. Its only running the the first @Test method. I am executing through Intellij TestNg plugin and not using the xml. I have selected class in configuration of TestNG execution.
Could anyone suggest anything for same.

Comment: Put in your code for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to export test result to HTML or XML report and check whether all tests got executed. Sometime Idea test runner console doesn't show all test result output but overall execution result should be shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll check in your test class, near class annotation you'll see something like this.
[Image to run all test in class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K81m.png)

I'm using Intellij idea15 community edition

In case, its a maven project. Just run mvn clean test. It'll run all the tests